# graph not change when scale changing in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have write a code for line graph. this graph have to change the scales from linear to power. now the code is working fine to change the scale from linear to power but my problem is, the lines on the graph does not change according to the scale. I have tried a lot, used various tricks but the lines are not changing. Please help me. below is my code. Thank a lot.

```js
// Define the line
var priceline = d3.svg.line() 
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.Yr); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.a_median); });
    

var data1 = [];
var dataNest = [];

   // Get the data
var rb = d3.selectAll("input").on("change", change);
   
d3.csv("data/salary.csv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.Yr = parseDate(d.Yr);
  d.a_median = +d.a_median;
    });


    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Yr; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.a_median; })]);

    // Nest the entries by symbol
    dataNest = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) {return d.occ_title;})
        .entries(data);

    data1 = data;
 
 // Loop through each symbol / key
    dataNest.forEach(function(d,i) { 
     //console.log(d);
        path = svg.append("path")
         .data(data)
            .attr("class", "line")
            .style("stroke", "grey")  
            .attr("id", dh+'tag'+d.key) // assign ID  'tag'+d.key.replace(/\s+/g, '')  
            .attr("d", priceline(d.values))
    });  
    
});

function change(){
    if(this.value === "linear"){          

          y = d3.scale.linear()
              .range([height, 0]);                      
           
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data1, function(d) { return d.a_median; })]);

            dataNest.forEach(function(d){
             svg.selectAll(".line")
              .data(data1)            
              .transition().delay(500).duration(5000)
              .attr("d", priceline(d.values))              
           });
           
          svg.selectAll(".y")
           .transition().delay(1000).duration(1000)
           .call(yAxis.scale(y));
          
        }


        if(this.value === "power"){         

           y = d3.scale.pow().exponent(3)
              .range([height, 0]);
            
     y.domain([0, d3.max(data1, function(d) { return d.a_median; })]);
            
            dataNest.forEach(function(d){                 
             svg.selectAll(".line")
              .data(data1)                           .transition().delay(500).duration(5000)              
              .attr("d", priceline(d.values))
                              
           })          

            svg.selectAll(".y")
           .transition().delay(1000).duration(1000)
           .call(yAxis.scale(y));    

           
        }        
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="plot" style="display:inline-block"></div>
 <div id="legend" style="display:inline-block"></div>
 <div id="scale" style="">
  <input type="radio" id="linear" name="r1" value="linear"><label for="r1">Linear</label>
  <input type="radio" id="power" name="r1" value="power" ><label for="r1">Power</label>
  <input type="radio" id="log" name="r1" value="log" ><label for="r1">Log</label>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the `d` attribute of the `path` as well, i.e. in your `change()` function run

```
svg.selectAll("path")
   .attr("d", priceline(d.values))
```

Comment: Thank you lars for your help. I already tried all these including your suggestion, but still its not working

Comment: Could you post a complete example that demonstrates the problem please?